# G Suite nameserver records for BIND DNS, how?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

so... i installed BIND on my own computer and looking at NSLOOKUP result, it does works. But i cant make it works for the gsuite stuff.

Any idea how?

currently the code is like this

```
$TTL 6h
@   IN SOA  mydomainname.org.   ns1.mydomainname.org. (
            2017110501
            10800
            3600
            604800
            86400 )

@   IN  NS  mydomainname.org.


@   IN A    MYPUBLICIPADDRESS
#The cnames are not needed, but nice to have. It will allow you to access mail via mail.domain.com
mail IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
calendar IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
docs IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
sites IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
start IN CNAME ghs.google.com.

#This is important
@ IN MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 3 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 3 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 5 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
@ IN MX 5 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
@ IN MX 5 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
@ IN MX 5 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
IN TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

after following this [cofigure bind for google apps mx record](https://serverfault.com/questions/310400/cofigure-bind-for-google-apps-mx-record)

but it doesnt work, and according to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=bramantya.org&dkim_selector= it says "domain must have mailserver" despite i already have mailserver using gsuite (it was on mail.mydomainname.org)

with nslookup, mydomainname.org shows correct address, but the nameserver cant find mail.mydomanname.org.

thankyou, 
pardon my english and explanation. If you need some more info ill reply as soon as i can (bad interent in jungle)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Turns out I only need to remove the hash tagged lines.

Comment: `;` is the comment character in the master file format.